# Alternative solution for deprecated "function.caller" or "arguments.callee.caller" in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web, firefox

As it's obvious from the title I'm looking for an alternative property or function for function.caller. I'm calling the callparent function in my own function, it works fine in Chrome but in Firefox I'm facing with null value in "this.callParent.caller".
I've researched this problem and read about the reasons for this change but I couldn't find a proper alternative and I really need a solution. Is it really like that JS didn't present an alternative for it's deprecated property?

```
`nAsyncInitialize: async function () {
    var me = this;
    me.nSearchFields = me._nGetSearchFields();
    me.callParent(arguments);
    var p = await me.nAsyncFillData();
    return p;
}`





`callParent: function (p) {
  var q,
  o = (q = this.callParent.caller) && (q.$previous || ((q = q.$owner ? q : q.caller) &&         q.$owner.superclass[q.$name]));
  return o.apply(this, p || b)
},`
```

I should mention that I'm working in "strict" mode and I preferably don't want to change it. I've tried argumet.callee but again it has null value.

Comment: The code looks very weird. Can you please explain what it does and why you think you need it this way, as it sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)...

Comment: @CherryDT My code did work correctly some times ago and even now it works in Chrom but it doesn't do the same in Firefox . I don't want to necessarily change it I just put it here to give a sense of what I'm working on. My actual purpose is to take the caller of the callparent mothod in my code.

Comment: I know but that's a strange thing to do in my opinion. The question is why you even need that. There is probably a better solution.

Comment: it's so wired... Why is there a difference result the different browsers? did you test it at the private page in the Firefox ?

Comment: @reyhanejanboori Yeah I've tried, didn't work. I've encountered some similar error in Odoo ClientSide programming too (somehow I could handle it there ). I'm not sure why but sometimes the browsers doesn't support the same configuration or structures as the other. Although it's possible that my question doesn't classify in this group of problems.